# Can not find file preprocessing.py in OpenNMT package

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

I used to use file preprocessing.py of OpenNMT package https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py to preprocess my raw data. Unfortunately recently I can not find that file in that package any more. Do you know where I can find that file or if you still have it, could you please send it to my email: tuankstn@gmail.com.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a new OpenNMT-py 2.0 release recently, and the previous version code has been moved to `legacy` branch.

You may find it at https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py/tree/legacy. Note there is no `preprocessing.py` file there, there is only `preprocess.py`:

[image]

Comment: If someone knows better, please post an answer, provide helpful information, leave a comment with a better suggestion at least, rather than downvoting helpful answers.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful to me.